# Alternatives for Monitoring and logging changes anywhere in file system [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: filesystem, logging, monitoring, zeitgeist, inotify

I would like to monitor and log following changes in file system:

1. Opening and closing of any file by any user.
2. Creation/deletion of file by any user.
3. Files downloaded by any user.

After some research I could find only 2 solutions:

1. [Zeitgeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_(free_software))
2. [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) (Disadvantage: lack of recursive support in directory)

Are there any other alternatives through which I can perform the above mentioned task or can I implement this somehow using some system calls?

What will be the best way to perform the above task?

OS details: Ubuntu 14.04, if it helps.

Comment: Nope @muru . The solutions in your link are for a specific file or directory. I have mentioned two solutions which I found which are relavent to me. I would like to know if there are some system calls that can help to do this task or if there is some other alternate solution. Presently I have made used of Zeitgeist API.

Comment: auditd is far more flexible than that.

Comment: Nonsense. Here we have a question explicitly asking how to make auditd non-recursive: https://superuser.com/questions/650714/auditd-auditctl-rule-to-monitor-dir-only-not-all-sub-dir-and-files-etc

Comment: Extremely sorry for my ignorance @muru. thank you very much for correcting me. I came across auditd solution before but was somehow misguided and discarded it.  Actually the logs and monitoring part is for the program I am working on. Thanks again.

Comment: @muru Do we have auditd part included in the dupe? If not, you may want to include it :)